# Spacing of column's in setSpanSizeLookup for recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `recyclerViewCategories.setLayoutManager` to set the number of columns dynamically

**Code:**

```
    /** Initilize the GridView **/
    private void initGridView() {
        GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mGridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(onSpanSizeLookup);
        recyclerViewCategories.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewCategories.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }


    GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup onSpanSizeLookup = new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return categoryHomeModelList[position].getDisplayType().equals("0") ? 2 : 1;
        }
    };
```

[image]

### What i am trying to solve: Vertical spacing is more than horizontal spacing ... How to reduce the vertical spacing between columns

Comment: can you show us the layout of recycler's item?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

For `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rcy_View"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="5dp" />  <== For side padding of list
```

For `Adapter` suppose you are using `LinearLayout` then:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">  <=  This is for each item spacing in list
    .....
    .....
</LinearLayout>
```

This will gives you 10dp spacing for each item. it also work for no of columns change.